# Wordpress Shortcode to get URL Parameters $_GET['name'] redirects for no reason at all

Tags: plugins, php, shortcode, redirect

Need some help in understanding how does WordPress Redirects work. While working with shortcode:

```
add_shortcode('name', 'get_name');

function get_name() {

   return $_GET['name'];

}
```

The page which was supposed to be running on:
https://localhost:8000/?page_id=2&name=test123 gets redirected to
http://localhost:8000/?page_id=2 for no reason at all.

I seem to have uninstalled and removed each and every plugin from the page I'm not able to understand how to diagnose it. Do we have any kind of log or something in wordpress to understand the cause of redirect? Also, how to make it work and visible?[image]

Comment: `name` is a reserved parameter: https://codex.wordpress.org/Reserved_Terms You need to use something else.

Comment: thank you very much for this @Jacob Peattie